# Unity: How to Delay button call by time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I desire to increment an float by 0.5 every time the user clicks the UI button and if the user presses the button for more than 2 second want to continuously increment the float by 0.5, to do so i use Event trigger (PointerDown, PointerUp) and call the functions in update. When i user the down below code i cant increment the float value continuously.

**Update Code**

```
void Update () {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (qStart, qEnd, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);

    if(Time.timeScale == 0)
        transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);

    clickCondition ();      
}
```

**PointerDown Function**

```
public void WhenIncreaseClicked()
{ 
    if (timeDown < 2.0f)
        IncreaseBPM ();
    else
        increase = true;    
}
```

**PinterUp function**

```
public void WhenIncreaseNotClicked()
{ 
    increase = false; 
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

**IncreaseBPM**

```
public void IncreaseBPM()
{
    if (speed < 12) 
    {
        speed += 0.05f;
        bpmText.GetComponent<BeatTextControl> ().beats += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("savedBPM", speed);
    } 
}
```

**ClickCondition**

```
public void clickCondition()
{   
    if(increase)
    { 
        IncreaseBPM();
    }
    else if(decrease)
    { 
        DecreaseBPM();
    }
}
```

**Start**

```
void Start () {
    qStart = Quaternion.AngleAxis ( angle, Vector3.forward);
    qEnd   = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, Vector3.forward);

    timeDown = Time.deltaTime;

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("savedBPM"))
        speed = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("savedBPM");
    else
        speed = 1.5f;
}
```

I have set `timeDown = Time.deltaTime` in `Start()`.

Comment: Could you share the method `clickCondition()` and the method where you set `timeDown`

Comment: added @ Orkhan Alikhanov

Comment: and the methods where you do operations with `timeDown`

Comment: i assign it in start

Comment: You just do one operation with `timeDown` and it's in `Start()`?

Comment: yes......then i check if it is greater than 2

Comment: i Am actually new to unity and c# :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no other code alters your `increase` variable, you'll be unable to increment it continuously because it will never be set to `true`.

In `Start()` you have a line `timeDown = Time.deltaTime;`, so `timeDown` will be equal to the number of seconds since the last frame. Not only is this an issue because `timeDown` never changes (`Start()` is only called once), but it's an issue because it's not likely to ever be above `2.0f` since a single frame is highly unlikely to take 2 seconds to complete. It will generally be a very small number, for example `0.06f`.

Due to this, in your `WhenIncreaseClicked()` method, the `if (timeDown < 2.0f)` will always equate to true. Thus the else clause is never executed and `increase` is never set to true.

To resolve this you could create a new boolean variable, e.g. `clicked` and set it to true at the start of `WhenIncreaseClicked()` and false at the start of `WhenIncreaseNotClicked()`. Then in `Update()` you can just add `Time.deltaTime` to `timeDown` if `clicked` is `true`. You'll also want to move that if/else outside of `WhenIncreaseClicked()` also, and into `Update()`, making sure it's only run when `clicked` is `true`.

For example:

```
void Update () {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (qStart, qEnd, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);

    if(Time.timeScale == 0)
        transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);

    if(clicked) {
        timeDown += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeDown >= 2.0f) // note the >= not <
            increase = true;
    }
    clickCondition ();

}
```

and `WhenIncreaseClicked()`:

```
public void WhenIncreaseClicked()
{ 
    clicked = true;
    IncreaseBPM();   
}
```

and `WhenIncreaseNotClicked()`:

```
public void WhenIncreaseNotClicked()
{ 
    clicked = false;
    increase = false;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

You can also remove the assignment to `timeDown` in `Start()` since it's not useful.

Comment: multiple increment even when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Unity documentation says about [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

> The time in seconds it took to complete the last frame.

When you set `timeDown = Time.deltaTime` timeDown  becomes a *tiny* fraction, for example `0.01621689`. Therefore, `timeDown < 2.0f` always returns `true` and your code never reaches `increase = true;` line.

Second point you should know is [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

> The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only). This is the time in seconds since the start of the game.

You used `Time.time` in your `Update()` method as `Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed)`. Bear in mind that `Time.time` can be enough large number representing the time in seconds since the start of the game as mentioned in document. When you do `Time.time * speed` the output number may be huge (assuming `speed > 1`) causing some problems. Luckily, you are using it inside `Mathf.Sin()` you get number only between [0, 1]. Probably, you intended to use `Time.deltaTime` instead.

---

Let's remember `Time.time`:

> The time in seconds since the start of the game

You can use this to check time difference.

```
float lastDownTime;
bool isDown;


void OnPointerDown() // Method name itself says when it should be called
{
    lastDownTime = Time.time;
    isDown = true;
}


void OnPointerUp()
{
    isDown = false;
}


void Update () 
{
    if (isDown)
    {
        if  (Time.time - lastDownTime  > 2) // 2 seconds
        {
            IncreaseBPM ();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Unity says about [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html):

> Except for `realtimeSinceStartup`, `timeScale` affects all the time and delta time measuring variables of the Time class.

So if you insist on using [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html), instead of using Time.time you should use [`Time.realtimeSinceStartup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) in above example.

Comment: Thanks your solution was all i needed, and using Time.deltatime in place of Time.time in update caused a problem. The rotation was too small.

Comment: I don't recommend using `Time.time`, it increases during gameplay. Use `Time.deltaTime` with large`speed`.

Comment: @VedSarkar why did you unaccept my answer and accept another one's suddenly?